# need a better solution to append html from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
   left_pos = (event_col[i] * xfactor * 100);
        //jquery part need cleaner
   $('.contain_textDiv')
       .append('<div class="sample_box1" style="margin-left:' + left_pos + '%;' + 'margin-top:' + Math.round(events[i].start) + 'px; width:' + Math.floor(95 * xfactor) + '%;' + 'position: absolute; height:' + Math.round(events[i].end - events[i].start) + 'px;"><div class="sample_boxHeader">Sample Layout</div><div class="sample_box_grayText">Sample Location</div></div>');
     }
```

This part of JavaScript code will go through the loop to change the current html style and add

```
<div class="sample"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="sample2"></div>
```

inside my HTML file, there already exist a `<div class="sample"></div>`

Anyone have a better solution to cleanup this part of code? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: what do you want to do here...

Comment: the jquery part is pretty long and messy, i want to find a better solution to append these two div into my exist div

Comment: Why did you think it was a good idea to edit out the JavaScript you wanted help with? That converted your question to: "here's some HTML, how do I improve the JavaScript that I'm not showing you."

Comment: If you think no-one's going to answer (except that you had three answers already at that point) then improve your question, don't make it meaningless.

Comment: i already got the answer. just up up that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending the DOM element as a string, create a new element in jQuery and append that:

```
var newEl = $('<div>').addClass("sample_box1").css({
    'margin-left': left_pos+"%",
    'margin-top': Math.round(events[i].start),
    width: Math.floor(95 * xfactor)+'%',
    //etc etc
});
$('.contain_textDiv').append(newEl);
```

Comment: it's a great approach! i was think about this way, then i was trying to use .html() method... then stuck there

Comment: the css part here is a little bit tricky. seems like i have to add single quote around margin-left and margin-top, like 'margin-top' and 'margin-left', also the console said absolute is not defined...

Comment: Yes, anything with a dash will need quotes. Make sure you put quotes around absolute as well, otherwise it's looking for a variable, not the string

Comment: just check Jquery API, i think alternative way is put every element inside double quote. so another question would be how can i append those two other div after your last line. just use .append().append() aftert the append(newEl)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to clean this up.  One way is to indent your code.  Another thing you can do is use jQuery's methods for setting style property values (so you don't have to worry about escaping and what not).

```
$('.contain_textDiv')
  .append(
    $('<div>')
      .addClass('sample_box1')
      .css({
        'margin-left': left_post + '%',
        'margin-top': Math.round(events[i].start) + 'px',
        width: Math.floor(95 * xfactor) + '%',
        height: Math.round(events[i].end - events[i].start) + 'px'
      })
      .append([
        $('<div class="sample_boxHeader">Sample Layout</div>'),
        $('<div class="sample_box_grayText">Sample Location</div>')
      ])
  )
```

(Code is untested but should get you started.)

Another thing to consider (and generally the best option) is using a JavaScript template engine.  There are many to choose from.  I've found [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) to be very efficient and lightweight, which is good when you only have basic templating needs.

Comment: the css part append fine, but it seems like the later two divs cannot be append like this way. the browser keep throw me errors

Comment: @JavaLeave You definitely can append divs that way.  There was a syntax error in my code.  It's fixed now.  We're appending an array of elements at the end, I used semicolons `;` instead of a comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Brennan's answer is a good clean approach. But if for some reason you prefer building it as a string, then here's an example of a little "using an Array like a StringBuilder" hack I like to use from time to time:

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    left_pos = (event_col[i] * xfactor * 100);
    var sb = [];
    sb.push('<div class="sample_box1" ');
    sb.push(  'style="margin-left:' + left_pos + '%;');
    sb.push(  'margin-top:' + Math.round(events[i].start) + 'px; ');
    sb.push(  'width:' + Math.floor(95 * xfactor) + '%;');
    sb.push(  'position: absolute; ');
    sb.push(  'height:' + Math.round(events[i].end - events[i].start) + 'px;">');
    sb.push('<div class="sample_boxHeader">Sample Layout</div>');
    sb.push('<div class="sample_box_grayText">Sample Location</div>');
    sb.push('</div>');
    console.log(sb.join(''));
    $('.contain_textDiv').append(sb.join(''));
}
```

Comment: will this making render slower than Brennan's solution?

Comment: I don't think it would make a noticeable difference either way unless the events array was very big. Besides, premature optimization and all that...

Comment: @JavaLeave It's actually faster... but I wouldn't recommend it.  You should never concatenate arbitrary data directly into HTML.  While you probably know where these numeric values are coming from today, you might not know where they come from tomorrow.  Troy's solution doesn't escape anything, which can lead to ambiguous CSS, HTML, and even injection vulnerabilities depending on how its used.